# Group dataframe by two columns and then shift values of other columns up by 1

Tags: python, pandas, data-structures, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe that is set up as follows:

```
Date      Name  A  B  C
09-01-10  Rose  11  2  5
09-01-11  Rose  12  6  7
09-01-12  Rose  9   7  14
09-01-10  Emma  20  70 24
09-01-11  Emma  19  74 19
```

I want to shift up the values for columns A, B, and C by 1 day so the new dataframe can look something like this:

```
Date      Name  A  B  C
09-01-10  Rose  12  6  7
09-01-11  Rose  9   7  14
09-01-12  Rose  NA  NA NA
09-01-10  Emma  19  74 19
09-01-11  Emma  NA  NA NA
```

I tried this:

```
data= data.groupby(["Date","Name"]).sum()
data = data.shift(-1)
```

and it ended up looking like this, which is incorrect:

```
Date      Name  A  B  C
09-01-10  Rose  12  6  7
09-01-11  Rose  9   7  14
09-01-12  Rose  20  70 14
09-01-10  Emma  19  74 19
09-01-11  Emma  NA  NA NA
```

Comment: Your explanation of what you want ("shift up the values by one") doesn't make sense...

Comment: I want to move the values in columns A, B, and C back by one day for both Rose and Emma.

Answer (score 1):

You need to groupby `Name` and shift columns `A,B,C` with `Date` column untouched, so just update columns `A,B,C` with the shifted version:

```
data[['A', 'B', 'C']] = data.groupby('Name')['A', 'B', 'C'].shift(-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know how I could shift one column up and one down?